# HTML Select Element: leaving option triggers Select mouseout Event in Safari

Tags: javascript, events, safari, html-select, mouseout

I have narrowed down a problem with some code I’m developing to the following:

If I assign a `mouseout` event listener to an HTML `select` element, it appears to be triggered whenever I move the mouse from one `option` element to another; not just when move the mouse outside of the `select`.

I have tested this on my Mac. It happens on Safari, but not on Firefox or Chrome, which suggests that it is not the intended behaviout.

I have tried using the Capture phase and stopping the event from going further in two ways, but Safari appears to genuinely believe that leaving an `option` also leaves the `select`. I have also tried using the `mouseleave` event, but I get the same issue.

How can I stop this from happening?

Sample

```js
var list=document.querySelector('div#list>select');
list.addEventListener('mouseleave',exit,true);
function exit(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 if(event.target!==this) return;
 console.log(`${this} ${event.eventPhase} ${event.target}\n`);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
 <select name="list" size="9">
  <option>Eight</option>
  <option>Five</option>
  <option>Four</option>
  <option>Nine</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Seven</option>
  <option>Six</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Two</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: So weird. This might help you. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189017/select-element-onmouseleave-event-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with all sorts of possibilities, I have found that you can check whether the mouse is inside the `select` element using `document.elementsFromPoint`.

Adding this line helped:

```
if (document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY).includes(list)) return;
```

```js
var list=document.querySelector('div#list>select');
list.addEventListener('mouseleave',exit,true);
function exit(event) {
// Check the mouse is inside select element
if (document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX,event.clientY).includes(list)) return;
event.stopPropagation();
if(event.target!==this) return;
console.log(`${this} ${event.eventPhase} ${event.target}\n`);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
 <select name="list" size="9">
  <option>Eight</option>
  <option>Five</option>
  <option>Four</option>
  <option>Nine</option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Seven</option>
  <option>Six</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Two</option>
 </select>
</div>
```